# Spring configuration for writing a regex that can match a list of strings ?

Tags: regex, spring

Is there a better way to write this regex which is actually a property on another class. The class will simply test if it is one of the strings mentioned below in "cpl". Also, if i want to fit the string separated by "|" on multiple lines for e.g. 
|R BERKS CTY RCP| #line 1 ends
|R BERKS CTY RCRP| #line2 ends 
then how do I write it ?

```
   <bean class="com.a.Class">
                        <property name="regEx">
                            <bean class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
                                <constructor-arg ref="cpl"/>
                            </bean>    
                        </property>
    </bean>    



 <bean id="cpl" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="(ST RCP|ST CT J DISC P|ST JUV CT|ST J ADMIN|R BERKS CTY J ADMIN|R BERKS CTY RCP|
                |R BERKS CTY RCRP|R CHESTER CTY RCP)">
    </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comment modifier x:

example:

```
<constructor-arg value="(ST RCP|ST CT J DISC P|ST JUV CT|ST J ADMIN|(?x)
                    (?-x)R BERKS CTY J ADMIN|R BERKS CTY RCP|(?x)
                    (?-x)R BERKS CTY RCRP|R CHESTER CTY RCP)">
```

or:

```
<constructor-arg value="(?x)(ST\sRCP|ST\sCT\sJ\sDISC\sP|ST\sJUV \sCT| #you can
                             ST\sJ\sADMIN|R\sBERKS\sCTY\sJ\sADMIN|R\s #put 
                             BERKS\sCTY\sRCP|R\sBERKS\sCTY\sRCRP|R\sC #comments
                             HESTER\sCTY\sRCP)(?-x)">
```

With the comment mode, the regex engine don't care about spaces, thus you must explicitly write all of them.

`(?x)` to activate the comment mode

`(?-x)` to desactivate